linking volumes and ports in helm chart

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "rmq.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "rmq.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "rmq.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "rmq.labels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.dockerRegistry }}{{ .Values.image.repository }}{{ .Values.image.imageName }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            {{- range .Values.service.ports }}
            - name: {{ .name }}
              protocol: {{ .protocol }}
              containerPort: {{ .targetPort }}
            {{- end }}
          env:       
          - name: "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ .Values.secretName | quote }}
                key: "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER"
          - name: "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ .Values.secretName | quote }}
                key: "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS"
          - name: "CERT"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ .Values.secretName | quote }}
                key: "CERT"
          - name: "CERT_KEY"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ .Values.secretName | quote }}
                key: "CERT_KEY"
          
          # ports:
          #     containerPort: {{ .Values.service.containerPort }}
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.httpGet.scheme | default "HTTP" }}
              path: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.httpGet.path }}
              port: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.httpGet.port }}
            initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
            periodSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.periodSeconds }}

          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.httpGet.scheme | default "HTTP" }}
              path: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.httpGet.path }}
              port: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.httpGet.port }}
            initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
            periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.periodSeconds }}
            
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          {{- with .Values.volumeMounts }}
          volumeMounts:
            {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.volumes }}
      volumes:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      
      dnsPolicy: Default

below is the values.yaml file

# Default values for rmq.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1
namespace: 
  create: true 
  name: ns-rabbitmq-dev

image:
  containerName: rabbitmq-3
  dockerRegistry: docker-bda.com.stihl-dns.net:443
  imageName: rabbitmq-3
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: /stihl/
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: "u20.04_002_r3_001"
  #image: 'docker-bda.com.stihl-dns.net:443/stihl/rabbitmq-3:u20.04_002_r3_001'

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # Automatically mount a ServiceAccount's API credentials?
  automount: true
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: ""

podAnnotations: {}
podLabels: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

# service:
#   name: rabbitmq-trial1
#   type: ClusterIP   
#   portName: rmq 
#   protocol: TCP
#   containerPort: 5672 
#   port: 5672 
service:
  name: rabbitmq-trial1
  type: ClusterIP   
  ports:
    - name: rmq
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
    - name: management
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672

ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    scheme: HTTPS
    path: /
    port: 5672
  initialDelaySeconds: 3
  periodSeconds: 3

readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    scheme: HTTPS
    path: /
    port: 5672 
  initialDelaySeconds: 3
  periodSeconds: 3

# livenessProbe:
#   httpGet:
#     path: /
#     port: http
# readinessProbe:
#   httpGet:
#     path: /
#     port: http

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80


volumes:
  - name: data
    hostPath: "./data"
    mountPath: "/var/lib/rabbitmq"
  - name: log
    hostPath: "./log"
    mountPath: "/var/log/rabbitmq"
  - name: config
    hostPath: "./config"
    mountPath: "/etc/rabbitmq"
    
# Additional volumes on the output Deployment definition.
volumes: []
# - name: foo
#   secret:
#     secretName: mysecret
#     optional: false

# Additional volumeMounts on the output Deployment definition.
volumeMounts: []
# - name: foo
#   mountPath: "/etc/foo"
#   readOnly: true

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}

secretName: certificate-secrets
env:
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: 'admin'
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 'admin2024'
  CERT: |-
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
               blablabla
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  CERT_KEY: |-
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                bla bla bla
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

  #Azure AD
    # APPLICATION_ID:
    # TENANT_ID:
    # CLIENT_SECRET:
    # AZURE_AD_JWKS_URI:

and this is service.yaml file
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  labels:
    {{- include "rmq.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    {{- range .Values.service.ports }}
    - name: {{ .name }}
      protocol: {{ .protocol }}
      port: {{ .port }}
      targetPort: {{ .targetPort }}
    {{- end }}
    # - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
    #   targetPort: {{ .Values.service.containerPort}}
    #   protocol: {{ .Values.service.protocol}}
    #   name: {{ .Values.service.portName}}
  selector:
    {{- include "rmq.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}



and this is secret.yaml file
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "rmq.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
stringData: 
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: {{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER | quote }}
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: {{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS | quote }}
  CERT: {{ .Values.env.CERT | quote }}
  CERT_KEY: {{ .Values.env.CERT_KEY | quote }}


I am trying to create a helm chart for RabbitMQ at my work and I am confused how to link volumes and multiple ports in it. I have shared all relevant files. Kindly tell me if I am making any mistakes as I am not able to deploy my helm chart on Rancher.
this is the error i am recieving in it at rancher. i have to do it using helm , and then transfer it to kubernetes cluster for checking
ImagePullBackOff (Back-off pulling image "docker-bda.com.xyzcompany-dns.net:443/xyzcompany/rabbitmq-3:u20.04_002_r3_001")


[![faced issue][1]][1]


What's the specific problem you're running into; what do you mean by "link volumes"?  It seems like you're trying to pass every possible Kubernetes manifest option via Helm values, would it be simpler to kubectl apply raw YAML files in Kubernetes standard syntax without using Helm?
